# How to convert utc timezone to specific time zone by dayjs?

Tags: javascript, datetime, timezone, momentjs, dayjs

I have UTC timezone DateTime `2022-11-28T23:58:29.670Z`
And want to get DateTime `2022-11-29T03:58:29.670Z` + 4 hours.
and at the end, I need `2022-11-29`

I tried several approaches
createdAt is 2022-11-28T23:58:29.670Z

```
const tz = 'America/Santo_Domingo';
const withtz = dayjs(createdAt).tz(tz);
const withtzday = withtz.format('YYYY-MM-DD');
```

And additional explanation. The user saves an item and I store it in UTC. But this item should show up in a specific timezone for this branch. So when I filter it by day I need to filter by createdBy but by particular timezone.

Comment: `new Date('2022-11-28T23:58:29.670Z').toLocaleDateString('sv',{timeZone:'America/Santo_Domingo'})` returns "2022-11-28".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've not been able to reproduce the problem. Following the Dayjs [documentation](https://day.js.org/docs/en/plugin/timezone) outputs the correct time UTC and for Santo Domingo.

However, the question seems to assume that Santo Domingo is UTC+4 when it is actually UTC-4.  So the hour calculation is: 23:58 - 4:00 = 19:58 on the same day. And this calculation matches the output from Dayjs.

**Snippet**

```js
let createdAt = '2022-11-28T23:58:29.670Z';

const tz = 'America/Santo_Domingo';
let utcdate = dayjs(createdAt);
const tzdate = utcdate.tz(tz);

console.log(
  'Created UTC:  ', utcdate.toISOString(), 
  '\nSanto Domingo:', tzdate.format('YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss'),
  '\nSanto Domingo:', tzdate.format('YYYY-MM-DD')
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/dayjs@1/dayjs.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/dayjs@1/plugin/utc.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/dayjs@1/plugin/timezone.js"></script>
<script>
  dayjs.extend(window.dayjs_plugin_utc);
  dayjs.extend(window.dayjs_plugin_timezone);  
</script>
```

Comment: thanks to a good catch. timezones make me crazy